# invert x and y axis Google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Consider the starter multiple line chart in google charts:

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
  data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

  data.addRows([
    [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
    [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
    [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
    [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
    [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
    [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
    [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
    [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
    [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
    [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
    [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
    [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
    [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
    [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
      subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

This plots a graph like this:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy73R.png)

cool.

But is there a way to plot this so that the x axis shows the dollars and the y axis shows the Days?

Thanks!

Comment: will you please clarify? do you want to format the y-axis as currency? and add more days to the x-axis?

Comment: I would .like the graph to be the same but rotated 90 degrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following option to rotate the axis'...

```
orientation: 'vertical'
```

see following working snippet...

```js
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
  data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

  data.addRows([
    [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
    [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
    [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
    [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
    [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
    [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
    [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
    [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
    [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
    [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
    [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
    [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
    [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
    [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
      subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
    },
    orientation: 'vertical',
    width: 900,
    height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="linechart_material"></div>
```